# Can IntelliJ IDEA properly format scala.html files and how do I enable it to do so?

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ultimate and CE format the following line in my main.scala.html file (in a Play application)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

As

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at(" stylesheets
/main.css")">
```

Yes. really.  It breaks up a quoted string.  I understand it thinks the string ends after `at(`, but this is an incorrect interpretation of the code.

Can IntelliJ correctly format this code?  How do I enable/use that formatting?

Comment: It's an open issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5570

Comment: @JamesWard you should put it as the answer, you deserve the reputation ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an open issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5570

This answer needed more characters to meet the minimum, so here they are.

Comment: fast-forward two years -- is there a way to format these files in the community edition of IntellijJ 14.x ?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.3 with the Scala plugin and reformatting and indenting of `*.scala.html` seems to be working much better.