# Formatting "*.scala.html" code in IntelliJ IDEA 15 community edition

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

Are there some special configuration settings that I should use in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1 Community Edition for `*.scala.html` files to be formatted correctly?

I read in **James Ward** comment to his answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478667/1065693
that it should work, a least partially.

So I installed Scala plugin and followed the instructions on importing a PlayFramework project: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html

Then I issued `Code -> Reformat Code`, but it produced a code that is not compiling any more, for example:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

@import play.i18n._

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="pl">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
</head>
    <body class="homepage">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

is turned to:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

@import play.i18n._

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="pl">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned(" stylesheets
    /main.css")">
</head>
<body class="homepage">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Breaking paths on `/` results in errors. I tried to change different settings in `Editor -> Code Style -> HTML` (or maybe I should use `Scala`?), but it didn't help. Is there something in the configuration that could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Play Framework and some other standards is not available in Community Edition (check [features pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) for more details)

Anyway you can try to workaround this problem i.e. by using single quotes for tag's attributes (note that W3C declares this as absolutely valid approach)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")'>
```

Comment: Thank you, using single quotes helped indeed.